# Rig: strange deformation of hairs (points at same position goes at different places)

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

I just rigged this character (using rigify, where the hairs were created by selecting the head, then `Shift-D` and `P > Selection` to put them on another object):

[image]

Unfortunately, when I select everything (armature last) and parent with automatic weight, the hairs does not move like expected as they "enter" inside the head (which is a bit strange as I would expect points being at the same position to end-up at the same position at the end):

[image]

Also, if I just move the hand, it also moves the hairs:

[image]

Any idea what I did wrong?

[image]

**EDIT**

I also tried the Rigify Animbox addon to add a walk cycle to my character, but unfortunately the walk is really strange, the hands are basically going through the body.

Answer (score 3):

I think I finally found the solution: I closed the mesh of the hairs (not sure why, but it was open), I recomputed the normals, and I reparented everything. Now, everything seems to be back to... normal.

**EDIT** ok, I was maybe a bit optimistic: it is better, but not perfect.

Answer (score 2):

problem is weight of hair vertex groups are mixed into other bones too along with head bone. to fix this do the following:

1: Remove all vertex groups in hair object,

2: select hair mesh then head(bone) in pose mode
ctrl+p (set parent to), select Bone

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is indeed better, but not perfect as the hairs are bound to a single bone while I guess the head slightly gets influenced by other bones as well. So when the hairs move, it does not exactly follows the displacement of the head.